# Why didn't main characters continue to move in War In Middle Earth?

Tags: commodore-64, lotr-war-in-middle-earth

A long time ago I played [War In Middle Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_in_Middle-earth) on the Commodore 64. As you played through you could somewhat recreate the events of the books. I took Frodo across the Misty Mountains, down through Mirkwood Forest, down towards Morder.

Very quickly my heroes would stop moving. Gandalf stopped moving half way through the mountains (perhaps because of the Balrog). After literally playing the same game over the course of a few years, I finally got Frodo within 3 spaces of Mount Doom. After that he simply refused to move anymore. Eventually all my troops were overrun by the increasing number of Orc armies wandering around.

Why did the main characters (and sometimes other random armies) just stop moving and sit in place indefinitely?

**Note:**

Looking at the Amiga and other versions, they appear to be significantly different from the C64 version. You only have two views in the C64 verison, the map view and the battle view.

Comment: ha, the good times when finding a good lotr game was near impossible. I remember it feeling like magic when ever I heard the words hobbit or lotr... then Hollywood got its hands on the games and now they are anything but magical :( I did enjoy the hobbit film mind you :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug, this game was know for having many, MANY bugs. Although most of them were graphical glitches, I have heard of people speak about bugs that completely broke their game and they had to start over.

Otherwise, although you have played the game for a long time and I would assume you know it very well, you should read the manual. It is actually very useful and descriptive. If you find you are doing everything correctly and your characters/forces circumstances should allow them to move you can then be sure it's a bug.

The manual in PDF form.
http://apple2online.com/web_documents/war_in_middle_earth.pdf

Comment: Wow, the Apple II version appears to have been significantly different from the Commodore 64 version. This [page](http://www.thehouseofgames.net/index.php?t=10&id=373) contains the version of the manual that was included in my C64 version.